# ASP.NET MVC3 Multi-Platform Support

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, mobile, web

In ASP.NET MVC3, what is the "suggested" way to build a web site that serves both desktop browsers and mobile devices?

The notion of simply building a single web site and having "switched" views based on browser type - strikes me as naive.  My SWAG is that an entirely seperate site should be created, with perhaps common libraries shared between the desktop-oriented site and the mobile-oriented site.

I say this not because view-switching is not possible, but because a mobile device likely requires an entirely different navigation scheme (and possibly POCO-DTO mappings, etc.).  Likewise I don't trust CSS as a means to present per-platform content, though it had been sold that way years ago.

So what is the reality of this endeaver?  Does MVC3 have a facility specifically for this goal, and is it reasonable for serious development?  Or should I stick to my intuition of having a  seperate mobile-oriented web site?

Incidently, my confidence of having a single mobile-platform site support multiple mobile devices (IPhone, Droid) is much higher - but I am more concerned about the mobile / desktop duality.

Comment: I think there is supposed to be support for it on MVC4? http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap

Answer (score 1):

Native app for mobile devices is the best way to go if performance is an issue here. If it's not give a try to css and fluent layout. This page is a great live example: http://css-tricks.com/.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an idea, rather than an answer to your question. Have you considered implementing a custom view engine? One of the MVC books that I have read, mentioned that you could write your own view engine if your view models will be rendered with XSLT. Can the same idea apply to mobile devices? Use the same view models, but have a different engine render your results.

Scott Hanselman wrote article on this topic in 2010 - it can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx).